# TemplateDoesNotExist at /inventory/render_results/ error message in django

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I am using code that I've used before but it is throwing an error, **'TemplateDoesNotExist at /inventory/render_results/'** and I cannot find the typo or logic miss.  The template does exist and when I review the code, the query is performing correctly.  I'm at a loss.

search_device_list.html

```
{% extends "inventory/base.html" %}
{% block content %} 

<h2 align="left">Search Page</h2> 

<form action="{% url 'render_results' %}" method="POST" > 

 {% csrf_token %}  
 <body>
 <table>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Locations: &nbsp;&nbsp; </b></td>
    <td>
        <select name="location_name">
        {% for locations in locations %} 
        <option value="{{locations.location_name}}">{{locations.location_name}}</option>{% endfor%}
        </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
  </tr>
  </table> 
  {% endblock content %}
```

render_results.html

```
     <html>

       <h2 align="left">Render Device List based on Location Choice</h2>

          <b> Locations:&nbsp;&nbsp; </b><br>{{locations }} <br><br><br>
          <b> Devices: &nbsp; &nbsp; </b><br>
              {% for device in devices %}{{device.device_name}} <br>{% endfor %}    </td>

          <br>
   <button type="submit" id="save">Save</button>
   </html>
```

views.py

```
def render_results (request):
    location_name = request.POST.get('location_name')
    my_devices = Devices.objects.filter(locations = Locations.objects.get(location_name = location_name))

    context = {"devices": my_devices,
               "locations": location_name}

    return render(request, 'inventory/render_results.html', context)  

  def search_device_list(request):
     locations = Locations.objects.all()
     print(locations)
     context = {"locations": locations}

     for locations in context['locations']:
        print(locations)

     location_name=request.POST.get('location_name')
     if request.method == 'GET':
            form = LocationsForm()
            print(locations)


     return render(request, 'inventory/search_device_list.html', context)
```

and finally urls.py

```
...
     url(r'^search_device_list/$', views.search_device_list, name='search_device_list'), 
     url(r'^render_results/$', views.render_results, name='render_results'),
```

Comment: Just to double check, the `render_results.html` is in the `templates/inventory/` folder in the same app as the `views.py` file.

Comment: Also check you have added your app to `INSTALLED_APPS` in the `settings.py` file

Comment: yes, thank you, I have checked both of those.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="{% url 'inventory:render_results' %}" method="POST" >
```

Comment: when I use that format I receive this error message: 
**NoReverseMatch at /inventory/search_device_list/

Reverse for 'render_results' not found. 'render_results' is not a valid view function or pattern name. **

Comment: make sure you have this folder tree at your project /appname/templates/appname/your_html_file.html and your appname must be in INSTALLED_APP (settings.py)

Comment: Then your post have a less information about urls.conf, i asume you have setting app_name to inventory, You need back to the original code and chek template tree again

Comment: Here is the tree in the settings.py file

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'inventory.apps.InventoryConfig',    
]

all of my other templates are working fine...

Comment: project_name_folder ----> app_name_folder -----> template_folder ------> app_name_folder ----> render_results.html. That is the correct path. ok so you must have this tree:  /projectname/inventory/templates/inventory/render_results.html

Comment: inventory_project ->inventory -->templates -->inventory -> render_results.html 
this is what I have

Comment: Ok now i am lost too. the last things i would do "stop and init server again".

Comment: I just did that; and you have been gracious and fabulous, I am still receiving the following error message:
** NoReverseMatch at /inventory/search_device_list/

Reverse for 'render_results' not found. 'render_results' is not a valid view function or pattern name. **

It also appears that the query isn't running anymore, it did run when I had

`<form action="{% url 'inventory:render_results' %}" method="POST" >  `

Answer (score 0):

Do you  have `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')` set in your settings file?

This would be in the templates section. This code should replace the empty list for DIRS = []

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/templates/

This is just speculation of course. It would help to see the full settings.py and urls.py. Also as previous stated, make sure the path to your templates is app_name/templates/app_name/html_file

Comment: thank you for responding.  I just put that code in the empty list for DIRS=[] and I am still getting the same error message.  I am also baffled as to why my other templates aren't sending this code.

Comment: I need to fix my post.  the name of the file is search_device_list.  I'll change that and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If your getting NoReverseMatch Error simply means you have an issue with the URL pattern either on the HTML end or in the URLconf. The reserve URL tag in your HTML templates can just be `{% url 'url_pattern_name' %}`

The tag you were first using `{% url 'inventory:render_results' %}`. Indicates that Django is to go to your URL conf, find the namespaced urls ie. `app_name = 'inventory'`. Then search in the namespace to find `render_results`. You can use either configuration but again the latter is stating your URL is namepspaced with `app_name='inventory'`.

I am not entirely sure if you can use the non-namespaced HTML tag `{url 'url_pattern_name'%}` with a namespace url config ex.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls